# Will the 'error' event ever be emitted on 'http.IncomingMessage' in a node.js http.request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I can create 4 error scenarios when calling `http.get(url, cb)`:

#### httpThrows()

Can be triggered with a wrong format of the url, or wrong callback, etc.

```
function httpThrows() {
    try {
        http.get("www.missing-protocol.com", res => {
            console.log(res.statusCode);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("http.get() throws an error.");
    }
}
```

#### requestError()

It the main error handler and triggers on some network related issue, e.g. DNS lookup failed or server not responding, etc.

```
function requestError() {
    var req = http.get("http://some-url-that-does-not-exist.com", res => {
        console.log(res.statusCode);
    });

    req.on("error", err => {
        console.log("req.on('error') called with error");
    });
}
```

#### errorCode()

Server responded normally so no network errors (can handle server errors).

```
function errorCode() {
    http.get("http://httpstat.us/501", res => {
        console.log("Got error code:", res.statusCode);
    });
}
```

#### responseError() (the problem)

An `http.IncomingMessage` is given in the callback as `response` or `res`. According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) it is a `Readable steam` and that steam can emit an `error` event.

```
function responseError() {
    http.get("http://some-ulr-with-error-halfway-through.com/", res => {
        console.log(res.statusCode);

        // This will never be emitted?
        res.on("error", err => {
            console.log("res.on('error') called with error", err);
        });
    });
}
```

So this last handler:

1. Is this event ever triggered when using `http.request` or `http.get`?
2. If so what can trigger the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my understanding the only way to end up with an error in that case is if there would be an issue with Node or the Engine and in both cases you can't do much about it.

In this situations I prefer not to handle those cases because you have less code to review and maintain.